# In a flutter app, how to load JSON data once and use it everywhere in the app?

Tags: json, flutter

The data for my Flutter app is having fixed 5000 rows with each row is having 14 fields.
I have stored this data in a JSON file under "/assets" directory of the project. I want to load this data of the JSON file only once and want it to be  available for all the screens. What is a good way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in your `main` before calling `runApp`, just make sure the loading time is not huge, as it may hurt the user experience.

Example:

```
MyData data;

Future<void> main() async {
  data = await loadMyData();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can I access "data" in other screens(.dart). Do I need to pass this in the constructor of other screen? Is there any better way to access it?

Comment: Are you going to mutate the data? If not, a global variable is fine. You can just declare it outside a class/function and import the dart file wherever you want to access it.